# MySql Adjacency List with full tree parents

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, adjacency-list, adjacency-list-model

I want to use adjacency list model in MySql following this tutorial:
[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) with query:

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';
```

My question is, i.e. if query returns:

```
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS | TUBE | NULL |
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS | LCD | NULL |
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS | PLASMA | NULL |
```

**How to modify query to get this result data + additional column for Leaf node ID (category_id)?**

```
ID | ELECTRONICS | NULL |NULL | NULL |
ID | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS |NULL | NULL |
ID | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS |TUBE | NULL |
```

> 1 .ID = id of ELECTRONICS
>
> 2 .ID = id of TELEVISIONS
>
> 3 .ID = id of TUBE

**I want full list tree and standalone parents to display, and their ID...**

Comment: Did you really implement the adjacency list model? The author warns about that: "Working with the adjacency list model in pure SQL can be difficult at best."

Comment: I'm just working with query you see! Need to expand it if possible.

Comment: The easiest way is to use UNION to get the result you want.

Comment: A rather late comment, but adjacency list models would need extra data in order to retrieve the full tree in a single query (without iteration of the parent nodes). It is best to implement a nested set model and use a stored procedure to build the initial tree for you using the parent relationship. Like so: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89693 This will allow you to maintain both nested set alongside the adjacency list on the same table. Optionally add depth and root for more advanced queries.